# How to evaluate HDBSCAN text clusters?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, evaluation, hdbscan

I'm currently trying to use HDBSCAN to cluster movie data. The goal is to cluster similar movies together (based on movie info like keywords, genres, actor names, etc) and then apply LDA to each cluster and get the representative topics. However, I'm having a hard time evaluating the results (apart from visual analysis, which is not great as the data grows). With LDA, although it's hard to evaluate it, i've been using the coherence measure. However, does anyone have any idea on how to evaluate the clusters made by HDBSCAN? I haven't been able to find much info on it, so if anyone has any idea, I'd very much appreciate!

Comment: sometime a t-sne plot can be fun to look at. sometimes it will give you encouragement as to if your features distinguish classes. I say *sometimes* because a good t-sne plot is nice...and not so good ones are meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the same problem everywhere in unsupervised learning.

It is unsupervised, you are trying to discover something new and interesting. There is no way for the computer to decide whether something is actually interesting or new. It can decide and trivial cases when the prior knowledge is coded in machine processable form already, and you can compute some heuristics values as a proxy for interestingness. But such measures (including density-based measures such as DBCV are actually in no way better to judge this than the clustering algorithm itself is choosing the "best" solution).

But in the end, there is no way around manually **looking at the data**, and doing the next steps - try to put into use what you learned of the data. Supposedly you are not invory tower academic just doing this because of trying to make up yet another useless method... So use it, don't fake using it.

Answer (score 3):

HDBSCAN implements [Density-Based Clustering Validation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/~zimek/publications/SDM2014/DBCV.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj0u5SL3fbjAhUsyaYKHVNgCXMQFjAAegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw2Ps4k6LZsKe3IpZruVD9Jx&cshid=1565386015787) in the method called [relative_validity](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#id35). It will allow you to compare one clustering, obtained with a given set of hyperparameters, to another one.
In general, read about [cluster analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) and [cluster validation](https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/cluster-validation-statistics-must-know-methods/).
[Here's](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/hdbscan/issues/178) a good discussion about this with the author of the HDBSCAN library.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `clusteval` library. This library helps your to find the optimal number of clusters in your dataset, also for hdbscan. When you have the cluster labels, you can start enrichment analysis using `hnet`.

```
pip install clusteval
pip install hnet
```

Example:

```
# Import library
from clusteval import clusteval
# Set the method
ce = clusteval(method='hdbscan')
# Evaluate
results = ce.fit(X)
# Make plot of the evaluation
ce.plot()
# Make scatter plot using the first two coordinates. 
ce.scatter(X)
```

So at this point you have the optimal detected cluster labels and now you may want to know whether there is association between any of the clusters with a (group of) feature(s) in your meta-data. The idea is to compute for each cluster label how often it is seen for a particular class in your meta-data. This can be defined with a P-value. The lower the P-value (below alpha=0.05), the less likely it happened by random chance.

*results* is a dict and contains the optimal cluster labels in the key *labx*. With `hnet` we can compute the enrichment very easily. More information can be found here: https://erdogant.github.io/hnet

```
# Import library
import hnet

# Get labels
clusterlabels = results['labx']

# Compute the enrichment of the cluster labels with the dataframe df
enrich_results = hnet.enrichment(df, clusterlabels)
```

When we look at the enrich_results, there is a column with *category_label*. These are the metadata variables of the dataframe *df* that we gave as an input. The second columns: P stands for P-value, which is the computed significance of the *catagory_label* with the target variable y. In this case, target variable y are are the cluster labels *clusterlabels*.

The target labels in **y** can be significantly enriched more then once. This means that certain **y** are enriched for multiple variables in the dataframe. This can occur because we may need to better estimate the cluster labels or its a mixed group or something else.

More information about cluster enrichment can be found here:
https://erdogant.github.io/hnet/pages/html/Use%20Cases.html#cluster-enrichment